# Selenium error in python: WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, webdriver

I try to connect to a webpage using `selenium webdriver` and `python 3.5.2` on my `ubuntu 16.04` remote server

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

I use [the tutorial](https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/) to install `selenium webdriver` and `Chrome` on `Ubuntu 16.04`
The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dev/txvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/dev/txvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/dev/txvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.4.0-36-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: I would get the same error on my windows machine when i installed the most recent chrome driver (2.29). I deleted the driver and downloaded an older one (2.27) and that fixed it for me.

This seems to be a prevalent error on VMs and containers, but i was getting it on my real machine!

Answer (score 0):

shared memory size problem
set this

volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm

[this answer save me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714948/selenium-unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash)